# Replacing substring with other text in variable inside a bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I've been trying to write a bash script. A part of it is supposed to replace a part of a string with nothing.

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
$dbname=$1
$dbNameActual="${$dbname/.sql/}"

date
echo $dbNameActual
```

I tried a number of suggestions from stack. But got nowhere. I tried adding sed, but that didn't seem to work.

The idea is that I have a script, and it takes in a **db import file name**, say `db250317.sql` and outputs `db250317` .

I'm running **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**.

Answer (score 3):

You don't put `$` twice in the expression, and you don't put `$` before the variable you're assigning to (this isn't PHP or Perl). It should be:

```
dbNameActual="${dbname/.sql/}"
```

Also, if the thing you're trying to delete is always at the end, you can use `%` to remove it:

```
dbNameActual="${dbname%.sql}"
```

Also remember to quote the variable when you use it later, in case the filename contains spaces. You should almost always quote variables, unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: Maybe also mention putting quotes around the argument to echo; `echo "$dbNameActual"` (unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)